# Why does SparkSQL require two literal escape backslashes in the SQL query?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-2.0

When I run the below Scala code from the Spark 2.0 REPL (spark-shell), it runs as I intended it, splitting the string with a simple regular expression.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

// Create session
val sparkSession = SparkSession.builder.master("local").getOrCreate()

// Use SparkSQL to split a string
val query = "SELECT split('What is this? A string I think', '\\\\?') AS result"
println("The query is: " + query)
val dataframe = sparkSession.sql(query)

// Show the result
dataframe.show(1, false)
```

giving the expected output

```
+---------------------------------+
|result                           |
+---------------------------------+
|[What is this,  A string I think]|
+---------------------------------+
```

But I am confused about the need to escape the literal question mark with not a single, but double backslash (here represented as four backslashes since we must of course escape backslashes in Scala when not using triple-quoting).

I confirmed that some very similar code written by a colleague of mine for Spark 1.5 *works just fine using a single (literal) backslash*. But if I only use a single literal backslash in Spark 2.1, I get the error from the JVM's regex engine, `"Dangling meta character '?' near index 0"`. I am aware this means the question mark was not escaped properly, but it smells like the backslash itself has to be escaped for first Scala and *then* SQL.

I'm guessing that this can be useful for inserting control characters (like newline) into the SQL query itself. I'm just confused if this has changed somewhere from Spark 1.5 to 2.1?

I have googled quite a bit for this, but didn't find anything. Either something has changed, or my colleague's code works in an unintended way.

I also tried this with Python/pyspark, and the same condition applies - double backslashes are needed in the SQL.

Can anyone explain this?

I'm running on a relatively simple setup on Windows, with Spark 2.1.0, JDK 1.8.0_111, and the Hadoop winutils.exe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

May be because backslash is a special symbol, used to concatenate multi-line SQLs.

```
sql_1 = spark.sql("SELECT \
    1 AS `col1`, '{0}' AS `col2`".format(var_1))
```

Answer (score 1):

Please do not compare your Spark 2.1 behaviour with your colleague's Spark 1.5; when it comes to escape characters, they are expected to behave differently. Quoting from [Spark docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/sql/index.html#rlike):

> Since Spark 2.0, string literals (including regex patterns) are unescaped in our SQL parser.

and

> There is a SQL config 'spark.sql.parser.escapedStringLiterals' that can be used to fallback to the Spark 1.6 behavior regarding string literal parsing.

So check your settings by `spark.conf.get('spark.sql.parser.escapedStringLiterals')`, and based on true/false use the single/double escape character.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some different ways to get the same result:

**Triple quotes**

```scala
spark.sql("""SELECT split('What is this? A string I think', '\\?') AS result""").show(false)
```

**Regex character escaping**

```scala
spark.sql("""SELECT split('What is this? A string I think', '\\Q?\\E') AS result""").show(false)
```

**Pattern.quote**

Suppose your string was in a DataFrame.

```scala
val df = Seq(
  ("What is this? A string I think")
).toDF("your_string")
```

You could leverage the Java regex quoting function to split the string as follows:

```scala
import java.util.regex.Pattern
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

df
  .withColumn("split_string", split($"your_string", Pattern.quote("?")))
  .show(false)
```

Here's the output:

```
+------------------------------+---------------------------------+
|your_string                   |split_string                     |
+------------------------------+---------------------------------+
|What is this? A string I think|[What is this,  A string I think]|
+------------------------------+---------------------------------+
```

See [this post](https://mungingdata.com/apache-spark/advanced-string-matching-with-rlike/) for more info.