# Spark 2.2/Jupyter Notebook SQL regexp_extract function not matching regex pattern

Tags: regex, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, jupyter-notebook

I'm using the regexp_extract Spark 2.2 SQL function in a Jupyter (Scala) notebook to match a string of 11 or more repeating characters.

Here's the regex:

```
^(.)\1{10,}$
```

Now, let's look at that pattern with the regexp_extract function. Here's how I've used it in my notebook:

```
spark.sql("SELECT REGEXP_EXTRACT('hhhhhhhhhhhhh', '^(.)\\1{10,}$', 1) as ExtractedChar").show()

+-------------+
|ExtractedChar|
+-------------+
|             |
+-------------+
```

Odd, no output. Let's make sure my regex pattern is actually correct. [Yep, looks right.](https://regex101.com/r/P49ajv/2)

You may be wondering why the regex pattern contains two "\\" characters, it's because it is an escape character so two are necessary. Here's some verification:

```
1. val string = "SELECT REGEXP_EXTRACT('hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh', '^(.)\\1{10,}$', 1) as ExtractedChar"
2. println(string)
SELECT REGEXP_EXTRACT('hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh', '^(.)\1{10,}$', 1) as ExtractedChar
```

Alright, let's make sure the regexp_extract function is working correctly:

```
spark.sqlContext.sql("SELECT REGEXP_EXTRACT('TESTING', '^.', 0) as test").show()
+----+
|test|
+----+
|   T|
+----+
```

Okay, maybe the issue is the Jupyter notebook? After checking and using the Scala REPL, I'm still having the same issue.

Any ideas why I'm unable to get this regex to successfully match?

Edit: Spark SQL is a requirement for this. I could create my own UDF using Scala; however, UDFs are black boxed by Spark meaning they will not be fully optimized.

Comment: Any reason you aren't using [scala.util.matching.Regex](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.9.2/scala/util/matching/Regex.html) ?

Comment: Yes, Spark SQL is required in this case to fit correctly into our procedure. I'll edit the post to include that.

Comment: no, I meant, doing whatever you are trying to do with the regex using Scala, and then sticking that in to the SQL query string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the solution. The SQL string needs to include 4 "\" characters, like so:

```
'^(.)\\\\1{10,}$'
```

Comment: It works but any doc to explain why this is necessary?

Comment: @mohit: the same query works in hive with 2 back slash, but in spark sql it works with 4 back slash.. interesting

Answer (score 3):

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41765033/14203873), four `\` characters are needed because `\` for two reasons:

1. `\` is a special character in SQL and needs to be escaped, so the query needs two of them.
2. The input is coming from a string where `\` also needs to be escaped. Just having `"\\"` would give a single `\`. To get two you need `"\\\\"`.