# REGEXP REPLACE with backslashes in Spark-SQL

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql, regexp-replace

I have a string containing \s\ keyword. Now, I want to replace it with NULL.

```
select string,REGEXP_REPLACE(string,'\\\s\\','') from test
```

But unable to replace with the above statement in spark sql

input: \s\help
output: help

want to use regexp_replace

Comment: (1) What database are you using?  (2) `NULL` is not something to replace in a string.  (3) Do you want `replace()`?

Comment: i want to replace with a blank..i'm working with sparksql. only regexp_replace is available.

Comment: Have you tried replacing it with an empty string instead?

Comment: yes Jake. it is failing. An error occurred when executing the SQL command:
select string,REGEXP_REPLACE(string,'\\s\\','') from test.   Invalid operation: Incomplete escape sequence found.  The error occurred while parsing the regular expression:

Comment: In your comment, you have two backslashes after the `s`, in your question only one. there is a significant difference as in the question you escape your `'` and that will definitely break it.

Comment: i tried all combinations. not working..can anyone pass the sql to do it? requirement is to use regexp_replace and remove keyword \s\

Comment: Edit your original post to show the exact input string, and the expected output.

Comment: Recently I wrote an answer to a similar question; maybe it will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41765033/why-does-sparksql-require-two-literal-escape-backslashes-in-the-sql-query/71575079#71575079

Answer (score 5):

To replace one `\` in the actual string you need to use `\\\\` (4 backslashes) in the pattern of the `regexep_replace`. Please do look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/4025508/9042433 to understand why 4 backslashes are needed to replace just one backslash

So, the required statement would become like below

```
select name, regexp_replace(name, '\\\\s\\\\', '') from test
```

Below screenshot has examples for better understanding

[image: Example input and output for reference]