# Regex in Spark SQL is resulting in wrong value but working fine on Amazon Athena

Tags: regex, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, amazon-athena

I am trying to extract text that exists inside root level brackets from a string in Spark-SQL. I have used the function regexp_extract() on both Spark-SQL and Athena on the same string with the same regex.

On Athena, it's working fine.

But on Spark-SQL, it is not returning the value as expected.

Query is:

```
SELECT regexp_extract('Russia (Federal Service of Healthcare)', '.+\s\((.+)\)', 1) AS cl
```

Output On Athena:

```
Federal Service of Healthcare
```

Output on Spark-SQL:

```
ia (Federal Service of Healthcare)
```

I am bumping my head around but can't seem to find a solution around this.

Comment: maybe this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/58529615. so you need `'.+\\\s\\\((.+)\\\)'` in Spark SQL.

Comment: @Emma let me check. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does the trick:

```
SELECT regexp_extract('Russia (Federal Service of Healthcare)', '.+\\\\s\\\\((.+)\\\\)', 1) AS cl
```

output:

```
+-----------------------------+
|cl                           |
+-----------------------------+
|Federal Service of Healthcare|
+-----------------------------+
```

The `s` is not being escaped in your example, that's why it falls as part of the group; you can also use the `regexp_extract` API directly which makes a cleaner solution:

```
.withColumn("cl", regexp_extract(col("name"), ".+\\s\\((.+)\\)", 1))
```

Good luck!